# get the value of radio button groups using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php loop code to generate radio button group

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
?>           
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input name="ans_<?php echo $i?>" value="option2" type="radio">
        The smallest resistance
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input name="ans_<?php echo $i?>" value="option2" type="radio">
        The largest resistance
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input name="ans_<?php echo $i?>" value="option2" type="radio">
        They have the same power loss.
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input name="ans_<?php echo $i?>" value="option2" type="radio">
        Voltage and resistance values are needed.
    </label>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
<button id="q_next" type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right savebtn" name="1">Save and Next</button>
```

when we click on this button the name attribute value increases by 1

I am using this name attribute to make the name of the radio button.

Now I want the jquery to get the value of selected radio of each group generated on the click of the button???

I tried this but its not working

```
$('#q_next').click(function() { 
  $quesid=parseInt($(this).attr('name')); 
  $ans=$("input:[name='ans_'"+$quesid+"]").val(); 
});
```

Comment: this code is for the test questions generated with the radio button options for each question. and next question is displayed when we click on the button and at that time i want to save the answer given by the user for that particular question. I don't want it to be done on the radio click it should be done only on button click..

Comment: i am using this but its not working
$('#q_next').click(function() { 
  $quesid=parseInt($(this).attr('name'));
  $ans=$("input:[name='ans_'"+$quesid+"]").val();
 });

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
var radio_groups = {};
$(":radio").each(function(){
    radio_groups[this.name] = true;
})

for(group in radio_groups){
    var selected = $(":radio[name="+group+"]:checked")
    if (selected.length > 0)
        alert('GROUP : '+ group + ',VALUE : '+ selected.val());
}
```

Comment: But It doesn't state that there on same page

Comment: then instead of iterating all radio_groups just get last radio_groups value

Answer (score -1):

Using jquery......
past below code

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#q_next').click(function(e){
        $("input:radio:checked").each(function() {
            alert(this.value);
        })   
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i don't want array i want each group's value separately.

Comment: this each function is also returning array it alerting all the previous groups selected option value but i want the value of the group on which  user clicked the button

Comment: @atjoshi, u mean u want to get selected Radio name ?