# Save input of radio button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a Question and Answer based site.Each question consist of 4 option.I want to save the Input of previous radio button so that user can come back to that question and see what he has given as the input??

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225373/get-the-value-of-radio-button-groups-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the value of radio button groups using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225373/get-the-value-of-radio-button-groups-using-jquery)